# exporting csv in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, csv, export-to-excel

I know how to export a csv file in php. Now I want to do this task in zendframe work.

1 I want to know is there any built in functionality that zend provides for this purposes or we have to write the same code that we use in simple php?

2 If I have to use same code then where should I put that whether in model or controller?

3 I have a view where user can select start date, last date and user andthen press enter. On the basis of that selection I want to exprot csv file.

Any one guide me how to accomplish this task

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To address your points in order

1. There is not a component in the Zend Framework that will generate and dispose of CSV files.
2. Your controller should just collect request parameters (i.e. date ranges from point 3) and initiate a response. I would create another class which can generate a CSV and then use [this Controller Action Helper, SendFile](https://github.com/noginn/noginn/blob/master/Noginn/Controller/Action/Helper/SendFile.php) to actually send the CSV file as a download.
3. Have your controller receive the request parameters using a form. Generate a CSV using your class (point 2) and then use the helper to send the response.

For generating CSV files it's recommended to use [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) rather than building strings yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a Zend Framework Action Helper - may be helpful. Note the site and code comments are in German.
http://blog.abmeier.de/zend-csv-action-helper

Comment: You should put a note about the language of the page :-) I was quite shocked it wasn't in english :-) :-)

Comment: Dead link... :(

Answer (score 0):

Building on regilero's answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4561138/2126442), I did come up with a Zend solution. Just use a complete query on the database itself:

```
$result = $this->_db->query(
     'SELECT * FROM `table_xy`'
    .'INTO OUTFILE \'tmp/outputfile.csv\''
    .'FIELDS TERMINATED BY \';\''
    .'ENCLOSED BY \'"\''
    .'LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\''
);
```

Just don't forget to set up the [necessary privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091427/mysql-into-outfile-access-denied-but-my-user-has-all-access-and-the-fold#comment17016006_6091447) for that user.