# MYSQL into outfile "access denied" - but my user has "ALL" access.. and the folder is CHMOD 777

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045, into-outfile

Any ideas?

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/home/myacnt/docs/mysqlCSVtest.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '*'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM tbl_property 
WHERE managerGroupID = {$managerGroupID}
```

Error:

```
Access denied for user 'asdfsdf'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: "ALL PRIVILEGES" does not include all privileges. Relevant to this case, it does not include the `FILE` privilege, which is needed for `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` statements. I've had several troubles with this mismatch between the English and the MySQL: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/96894/53784

Comment: If you then run into "The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement" take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Try executing this SQL command:

```
> grant all privileges 
  on YOUR_DATABASE.* 
  to 'asdfsdf'@'localhost' 
  identified by 'your_password';
> flush privileges;
```

It seems that you are having issues with connecting to the database and not writing to the folder you’re mentioning.

Also, make sure you have granted `FILE` to user `'asdfsdf'@'localhost'`.

```
> GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'asdfsdf'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Everything looks good with that, even in cpanel EVERYTHING is checked

Comment: @Shackrock: check out updated answer. Make sure you've granted `FILE` to the user.

Comment: There are two issues here. 1) GRANT ALL does not do GRANT FILE.  2) GRANT FILE only works with \*.\* (i.e. globally). Both are bugs in MySQL.

Comment: FYI, think carefully before doing this is you aren't the db admin.  Mine was not pleased to find I'd changed the privileges ("Nooooooo!"). :-)

Comment: Seems like it also has issues writing to locations in the filesystem other than /var/lib/mysql, which seems contrary to the documentation. Even when the target folder is owned by mysql:mysql and everyone has rwx permissions and/or is called using sudo... (coming from Ubuntu here)

Comment: This worked fro me https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cannot-create.html starting service with a directory tmpdir=c:\temp

Comment: You don't need to use `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after `GRANT`. That's only needed if you modify the privileges table with SQL instead of using `GRANT`.

Comment: Didn't work for me until I restarted mysql server (MariaDB)

Answer (score 75):

Honestly I didnt bother to deal with the grants and this worked even without the privileges:

```
echo "select * from employee" | mysql --host=HOST --port=PORT --user=UserName --password=Password DATABASE.SCHEMA > output.txt
```

Comment: That's because you're just doing a regular SELECT, not a SELECT INTO OUTFILE (a .csv file in this case).

Comment: This is a bad way to do it for larger tables because the client buffers the entire result set before it puts anything out to the file.

Comment: MySQL will tab delimit the file using this method, which is perfect.  After trying a dozen file permissions, MySQL settings, and various grants, all spanning 5 or 6 different help pages, this worked.  Save yourself the headache and use this.

Comment: Don't forget to switch to the appropriate codepage before using this method, e.g. "chcp 1252" or "chcp 65001" if there are special characters in the exported data.

Comment: Another issue with this is escaping of NULLs. Using INFILE from the output of this command will result in the string literal "NULL" being imported rather than an actual NULL, which is escaped using \N.

Comment: I agree with Paul K. Nothing else worked except this answer. Thanks. It inspired my answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/245383/18098

Comment: This is the most practical answer so far, others are so dependent on privileges that not everyone has control over

Comment: Note also that if your data has any newlines in it, the tab-delimited lines get messed up. But if not, then this is the easiest solution!

Answer (score 25):

As @fijaaron says,

1. `GRANT ALL` does not imply `GRANT FILE`
2. `GRANT FILE` only works with `*.*`

So do

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO user;
```

Answer (score 6):

Since cP/WHM took away the ability to modify User privileges as root in PHPMyAdmin, you have to use the command line to:

```
mysql>  GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

Step 2 is to allow that user to dump a file in a specific folder. There are a few ways to do this but I ended up putting a folder in :

```
/home/user/tmp/db
```

and

```
chown mysql:mysql /home/user/tmp/db
```

That allows the mysql user to write the file. As previous posters have said, you can use the MySQL temp folder too, I don't suppose it really matters but you definitely don't want to make it 0777 permission (world-writeable) unless you want the world to see your data. There is a potential problem if you want to rinse-repeat the process as `INTO OUTFILE` won't work if the file exists. If your files are owned by a different user then just trying to `unlink($file)` won't work. If you're like me (paranoid about 0777) then you can set your target directory using:

```
chmod($dir,0777)
```

just prior to doing the SQL command, then

```
chmod($dir,0755)
```

immediately after, followed by `unlink(file)` to delete the file. This keeps it all running under your web user and no need to invoke the mysql user.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the solutions but it still wasn't sufficient. After some more digging I eventually found I had also to set the 'file_priv' flag, and restart mysql.

To resume :

Grant the privileges :

```
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
  ON my_database.* 
  to 'my_user'@'localhost';

> GRANT FILE ON *.* TO my_user;

> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Set the flag :

```
> UPDATE mysql.user SET File_priv = 'Y' WHERE user='my_user' AND host='localhost';
```

Finally restart the mysql server:

```
$ sudo service mysql restart
```

After that, I could write into the `secure_file_priv` directory. For me it was /var/lib/mysql-files/, but you can check it with the following command :

```
> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

Answer (score 3):

For future readers, one easy way is as follows if they wish to export in bulk using bash,

```
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ mysql -u someuser -p test -e "select * from offices"
Enter password: 
+------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| officeCode | city          | phone            | addressLine1             | addressLine2 | state      | country   | postalCode | territory |
+------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| 1          | San Francisco | +1 650 219 4782  | 100 Market Street        | Suite 300    | CA         | USA       | 94080      | NA        |
| 2          | Boston        | +1 215 837 0825  | 1550 Court Place         | Suite 102    | MA         | USA       | 02107      | NA        |
| 3          | NYC           | +1 212 555 3000  | 523 East 53rd Street     | apt. 5A      | NY         | USA       | 10022      | NA        |
| 4          | Paris         | +33 14 723 4404  | 43 Rue Jouffroy D'abbans | NULL         | NULL       | France    | 75017      | EMEA      |
| 5          | Tokyo         | +81 33 224 5000  | 4-1 Kioicho              | NULL         | Chiyoda-Ku | Japan     | 102-8578   | Japan     |
| 6          | Sydney        | +61 2 9264 2451  | 5-11 Wentworth Avenue    | Floor #2     | NULL       | Australia | NSW 2010   | APAC      |
| 7          | London        | +44 20 7877 2041 | 25 Old Broad Street      | Level 7      | NULL       | UK        | EC2N 1HN   | EMEA      |
+------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

**If you're exporting by non-root user then set permission like below**

```
root@ideapad:/tmp# mysql -u root -p
MariaDB[(none)]> UPDATE mysql.user SET File_priv = 'Y' WHERE user='someuser' AND host='localhost';
```

**Restart or Reload mysqld**

```
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ sudo su
root@ideapad:/tmp#  systemctl restart mariadb
```

**Sample code snippet**

```
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ cat test.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

user="someuser"
password="password"
database="test"

mysql -u"$user" -p"$password" "$database" <<EOF
SELECT * 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/csvs/offices.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM offices;
EOF
```

**Execute**

```
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ mkdir -p /tmp/csvs
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ chmod +x test.sh
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ ./test.sh 
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ cat /tmp/csvs/offices.csv 
"1"|"San Francisco"|"+1 650 219 4782"|"100 Market Street"|"Suite 300"|"CA"|"USA"|"94080"|"NA"
"2"|"Boston"|"+1 215 837 0825"|"1550 Court Place"|"Suite 102"|"MA"|"USA"|"02107"|"NA"
"3"|"NYC"|"+1 212 555 3000"|"523 East 53rd Street"|"apt. 5A"|"NY"|"USA"|"10022"|"NA"
"4"|"Paris"|"+33 14 723 4404"|"43 Rue Jouffroy D'abbans"|\N|\N|"France"|"75017"|"EMEA"
"5"|"Tokyo"|"+81 33 224 5000"|"4-1 Kioicho"|\N|"Chiyoda-Ku"|"Japan"|"102-8578"|"Japan"
"6"|"Sydney"|"+61 2 9264 2451"|"5-11 Wentworth Avenue"|"Floor #2"|\N|"Australia"|"NSW 2010"|"APAC"
"7"|"London"|"+44 20 7877 2041"|"25 Old Broad Street"|"Level 7"|\N|"UK"|"EC2N 1HN"|"EMEA"
```