# SQL into outfile - where is the file stored? (MySQL, Windows)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, windows

I am using MySQL and would like the results of the following query to be stored in a csv file locally on my machine:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'mysqlresults.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM table;
```

I have searched for the file and it could not be located anywhere on the disk so it is not in the 'data' directory.

Comment: is mysql server on local machine or remote machine ?

Comment: It's on the local machine

Comment: try this command: SELECT * FROM table INTO OUTFILE 'mysqlresults.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ;

Comment: Still, the file is nowhere to be found

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Be default it stored in the MySQL's data directory.
And you can check your data directory by command:

```
show variables like 'datadir';
```

You can't store it locally with this command running on remote server, you need to download the file from the server.

You can also use this command:

```
SELECT * FROM table INTO OUTFILE 'mysqlresults.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ;
```