# Permission denied mysql outfile

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand which user is called when I execute a MySQL procedure because my procedure tries to create a file but the file can not be created because of a permission problem.

Here is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `EXPORT_TEST`()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

DECLARE VAR_INS INT(10);
DECLARE VAR_DT_DEBUT DATETIME;


SET VAR_DT_DEBUT = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

INSERT INTO BC_ALIM (NOM_TABLE, DATE_DEBUT)
  VALUES('EXPORT_TEST', VAR_DT_DEBUT);

BEGIN

SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/home/bureau/IMPORTS/fichierSortie3.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
FROM db_baby_concept.BC_TYPE_LIVRAISON;
END;
END
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: When you run a procedure it uses the permissions of the creator by default.

Comment: L'utilisateur MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL stored procedures have a `SQL SECURITY` characteristic, which specifies security contact in which the procedure code runs. This can be either `DEFINER` or `INVOKER`, and the default is `DEFINER`. So when you run your stored procedure, it executes with the permissions of the user who defined the procedure; if they don't have the `FILE` privilege, it won't be able to create the file.

You can set the procedure's security to `INVOKER` instead. Then it will use your permissions rather than the creator's.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procName()
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN 
    ...
END;
```

Also, the file is written by the MySQL server process, so the Linux userid used for the server needs to have write permission to the directory containing the file. So you probably need to make your `IMPORTS` directory world-writable. And if the `secure_file_priv` system variable is set, you can only write to the directory named there.

Comment: I have changed the procedure but I still have access denied (See my post) Thx

Comment: Is the IMPORTS directory world-writable?

Comment: Yes chmod -R 777

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359005/select-into-outfile-permission-denied-but-the-user-can-write-to-the-directory/30359605

Comment: This does not impact anything on the database?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you just make changes that affect writing files, it shouldn't affect anything else.

Comment: Not work :'( All users of the database have the File_priv at Y

Comment: There are lots of other questions about this topic.

Comment: its working with this Prevent accessing /home, /root and /run/user
ProtectHome=true