# SELECT * FROM .. INTO OUTFILE and save on hosting or send FTP - HOW TO?

Tags: save, hosting, mysql-error-1045, select-into-outfile

I need help. When I try this - SELECT * FROM .. INTO OUTFILE - on local, everything is ok. When I try it on my hosting, I receive error message #1045 - Access denied for user '..'@'%' (using password: YES) . How to do it make it work? Thanks for any advice :)

Comment: Ask your host provider, they might not allow this functionality or it might be  just a missing/wrong configuration.

Comment: Provider I asked first of all, but he don't know nothing, and SELECT feature is enabled. I try to perform an action through the admin account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL into outfile "access denied" - but my user has "ALL" access.. and the folder is CHMOD 777](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091427/mysql-into-outfile-access-denied-but-my-user-has-all-access-and-the-fold)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by using fputcsv() - simply by using the SELECT,  from the database i take field up and in the PHP script I created CSV file :)