# MariaDB by commandline query gives error

Tags: mariadb

MariaDB[databaseName]> select * from tableName INTO OUTFILE 'order.txt';

Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'userName'@'%' (using password: YES)

How do I fix this please?

Comment: What do you have for `SHOW GRANTS FOR  'userName'@'%';`?  (but leave out the pwd.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091427/mysql-into-outfile-access-denied-but-my-user-has-all-access-and-the-fold

Comment: GRANT USUAGE ON *.* TO 'userName'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxx" WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 200

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'datasbaseName'.* TO 'userName'@'%'

Comment: Can somebody help,please?