# Permission denied while exporting csv file from mySQL (MariaDB) to targeted folder

Tags: mysql, database, raspberry-pi, mariadb

My understanding is that exporting a file (e.g. csv) from `MariaDB` is restricted to specified folders by default. Thus, I have been accessing my exported files at the `tmp` folder so far. I wanted to ask if there was a way to change this to another folder i.e. `/home/user/projects`? I am using Raspbian Stretch as my OS. As a root user of my `SQL databas`e, I checked that I have full grant privileges.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, when I query with 
`MariaDB [mydatabase]> SELECT * from table1 into outfile '/home/user/projects/file1.csv';`, I get this error:

`ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/home/user/projects/file1.csv' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")`,

Is there something else I can do to be able to export my files to a folder of my choosing?

**Updates**: So far, I tried chmod 755 and 777 methods and creating a new user in the SQL client with granting of full privileges and file (and then logging in as that user to make the query), but have had no success .

Comment: I am using Raspbian Stretch OS. I have been getting denied permission responses in mySQL program when trying to output the file to `home/pi/projects`. However, no problems when exporting file to `tmp` folder.

Comment: Please provide the output of `ls -ld /home/user/projects/`

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem and managed to solve by exporting the data to:

```
 '/var/tmp/file1.csv'
```

I made the login in mariadb like this:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

I hope this help you!

Comment: This works for me too. For some reason I can't seem to create a new folder anywhere with permissions to grant mysql/mariadb write access, but `/var/tmp` seems to have the necessary permissions.

Answer (score 2):

it's a os directory permission issue. Change ownership to mysql with permission and try.

Comment: How can I change the ownership? Is there a file that I can edit?

Comment: chown mysql:mysql /home/pi/projects/     and try.


if this doesn't work, change the permission.
chmod 755  /home/pi/projects/       and try.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I've tried both `chown mysql:mysql /home/pi/projects/` and `sudo chown mysql:mysql /home/pi/projects/` and launch the mysql client, but still the query to output the file to that folder doesnt work. I'm still getting `ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/home/pi/projects/file1.csv' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")`
 What do you mean by changing permission?

Comment: `chmod 777 /home/pi/projects/`is not working for me as well. I also tried the solution here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091427/mysql-into-outfile-access-denied-but-my-user-has-all-access-and-the-fold, where I created another user (pi) and granted all and file privileges, then log into the mysql client again as the pi user, and did the same query, but still no success.

Comment: ok. Can you check  entries in below file. cat /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld

Comment: and add below entries in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld  file and restart apparmor  '/etc/init.d/apparmor restart'  

/home/pi/projects/  r,
/home/pi/projects/** rwk,

Comment: On opening `cat /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`, it states:

Comment: `# This file is intensionally empty to disable apparmor by default for newer
# versions of MariaDB, while providing seamless upgrade from older versions
# and from mysql, where apparmor is used.
# By default, we do not want to have any apparmor profile for the MariaDB
# server. It does not provide much useful functionality/security, and causes`

Comment: `# several problems for users who often are not even aware that apparmor
# exists and runs on their system.
# Users can modify and maintain their own profile, and in this case it will
# be used.
# When upgrading from previous version, users who modified the profile
# will be promptet to keep or discard it, while for default installs
# we will automatically disable the profile.`

Comment: please share the below commands output
ls -al /home/pi/ | grep projects

AND

ps -ef | grep mysql

Comment: `mysqlgrep: projects: No such file or directory
grep: AND: No such file or directory
grep: ps: No such file or directory`

Comment: Can you share the "projects" directory (which is under /home/pi/) ownership and permission. 
for e.g. refer to below output. 


drwxr-xr-x 2 root       root       4.0K Dec 29 06:00 projects

Comment: Irrespective of who runs mysql and the -u argument, the outfile is written by the DAEMON.  If in doubt, try OUTFILE '/tmp/whatever' and check the ownership of the resulting file.