# How to use OUTFILE in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, file-io

I am trying to download the million of records from the database using OUTFILE. I am getting this error
Error Number: 1290

The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

SELECT name, cp_id FROM campaign INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/html/test_csv/1184445179_180912015611.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ';

Filename: models/Admin_model.php

Line Number: 976

**below is the model code:**

$pth = rand().'_'.date('ymdhis').'.'.'csv';
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test_csv/'.$pth;
$ad = $this->db->query("SELECT name, cp_id FROM campaign INTO OUTFILE '$path' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';")

Comment: Since mysql is running with --secure-file-priv can't you use codeigniter function to output csv from a query result? https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/utilities.html#export-a-query-result-as-a-csv-file

Comment: yes i am using codeigniter

Comment: Them try the built in tool and see if you get any difference. Otherwise I think you have to enable OUTFILE in your server. For that you can see this thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091427/mysql-into-outfile-access-denied-but-my-user-has-all-access-and-the-fold

Comment: Ok, let me try to connect to the server using putty file and run the below command, if it works, i will reply you what is going wrong or not... Thanks..

Comment: i will run the below comman: -      grant all privileges 
  on YOUR_DATABASE.* 
  to 'asdfsdf'@'localhost' 
  identified by 'your_password';
> flush privileges;