# Run MYSQL select query with join in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-18.04

I have the below query that I am trying to run and save the result to a file. But I don't know the exact syntax as I am new to MYSQL.

```
SELECT b.*,c.* FROM  tableb as b JOIN tablec as c ON c.rootid = b.id WHERE b.status = 2;
```

I want to run this query on a MYSQL shell inside Ubuntu terminal. And save the results in a file. Can someone guide on the exact syntax please? I am using MYSQL Ver 14.14 Dist 5.7 version on ubuntu 18.04 terminal. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I tried thebelow query exactly and I see error:

```
mysql -u prod -p -e"SELECT tabler.* , tablec.* FROM tablec JOIN tableo ON tablec.id = tableo.id JOIN tabler ON tableo.id = tabler.id WHERE tabler.status = 4;">/tmp/tbldata;
```

I am seeing this error:

> you have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds
> to your mysql server version

any help?

**SECOND UPDATE** my final query looks like below:

```
SELECT tabler.* , tablec.* INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/data.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM tablec JOIN tableo ON tablec.id = tableo.id JOIN tabler ON tableo.id = tabler.id WHERE tabler.status = 4;
```

I am seeing the below error:

> access denied you need (at least one of) the file privilege(s) for
> this operation

my used prod does not have rights. How do I give rights to write to the csv file?

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql -u root -p -e"SELECT b.*,c.* FROM  tableb as b JOIN tablec as c ON c.rootid = b.id WHERE b.status = 2" > /tmp/table_data
```

Note: Use your username instead of `root`.

Another way, you can use it `INTO OUTFILE`

```
SELECT b.*,c.* 
FROM  tableb as b 
JOIN tablec as c ON c.rootid = b.id 
WHERE b.status = 2
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/table_data.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: I tried this query and I am constantly getting error. Updated my question with error. Pls help

Comment: You have included `;` in your query. Remove that. Keep space before and after `>`

Comment: Thanks. Now I am seeing file permission error: access denied you need (at least one of) the file privilege(s) for this operation. Editing the question with my latest query

Comment: for access rights try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091427/mysql-into-outfile-access-denied-but-my-user-has-all-access-and-the-fold